# how to set up class instance control events?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class Viewer that creates two linked `FastColoredTextBoxes`. I want the two boxes to scroll together horizontally. I have this code:

```
public class Viewer : Panel
{
     public FastColoredTextBox HeaderRow = new FastColoredTextBox();
     public FastColoredTextBox Editor = new FastColoredTextBox();    

     public Viewer(int _Top, int _Left, int _Height, int _Width, bool _HasHeaderRow, Control control)
     {
         this.Editor.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(Editor_Scroll);
     }

     void Editor_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
     {
          if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
          {
              this.HeaderRow.HorizontalScroll.Value = this.Editor.HorizontalScroll.Value;
          }
          this.HeaderRow.UpdateScrollbars();
      }
 }
```

It doesn't work. I've never tried to do attach events to controls in a class instance before. If I declare the controls in my form and attach a very similar event (minus the .this's) it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: second to last line of code should read:

Comment: `this.HeaderRow.HorizontalScroll.Value = this.Editor.HorizontalScroll.Value;`

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect these changes.

Comment: Edit done. I could still really do with knowing where I'm going wrong here please someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think that for the next time try to tell yourself " what could it be?" and maybe debug a little, like a breackpoint for example. as you probably understood,  you had a little mistake in the line

```
this.HeaderRow.HorizontalScroll.Value = this.HeaderRow.HorizontalScroll.Value;
```

you meant to write

```
HeaderRow.HorizontalScroll.Value = Editor.HorizontalScroll.Value;
```

you just got mixed between the two or something, which happens to all of us. but the first thing i would do is to think and debug it, check the values and let someone look at it. only then post it here.

Comment: sorry, but I did add that correction as a comment myself almost immediately after I posted it. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: @RichJohnstone if i had more time i would have writen it myself and check it, but for now look here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486221/scrollbar-value-set-incorrectly

Comment: Thanks, No Idea For Name, for trying to help. Unfortunately that page was not my solution. The scrollbar code works as I have tested it on two controls created directly in my UI. It's getting the events hooked up properly with Controls created as class instance members that is my problem. Any help gratefully received. thanks again.